# SQL найти оба значения из другой таблицы

Tags: sql

Дано две таблицы:

position

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

header

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Необходимо вывести id, из таблицы header, где в таблице position для него присутствует позиция 389577 и 389578 ( т.е. обе)

Если просто сджоинь через in, выведет все id

select h.number from header h

join position p on h.id=p.id

where p.position in ('389577','389578')

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А по моему условию, хотелось бы только 283, тк только он содержит обе позиции

Comment: См. "реляционное деление". Типичное решение - отбор по заданным значениям, группировка, подсчёт количества уникальных значений и сравнение с количеством заданных значений.

Answer (score 0):

```sql
SELECT h.number 
FROM header h
JOIN position p USING (id)
WHERE p.position IN ('389577', '389578')
GROUP BY h.number 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT p.position) = 2
```

Comment: спасибо, изучу эти моменты..

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]